# configuring ingress for dask-jupyter helm chart deployment

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kubernetes-helm, dask

I deployed a single-user dask-jupyter helm chart on a k8s cluster (https://github.com/dask/helm-chart/tree/main/dask).

$ helm ls

```
NAME    NAMESPACE       REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART           APP VERSION
pangeo  wifire-quicfire 6           2021-11-22 15:29:38.809774 -0800 PST    deployed    dask-2021.11.2  2021.11.2
```

$ kubectl get svc pangeo-dask-jupyter pangeo-dask-scheduler

```
NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
pangeo-dask-jupyter     ClusterIP   10.105.206.19   <none>        80/TCP            20h
pangeo-dask-scheduler   ClusterIP   10.107.121.88   <none>        8786/TCP,80/TCP   20h
```

I'm trying to expose an external ip.  My k8s does not allow the use of the LoadBalancer service so I'm trying to enable the ingress instead.

For exposing an external ip, I’m trying to enable ingress following this template:
https://github.com/dask/helm-chart/blob/main/dask/templates/dask-jupyter-ingress.yaml

Here’s the ingress part of my values.yaml:

```
  ingress:
    enabled: true  
    tls:   
      - hosts: 
        - wifire-commons-pangeo-jupyter.nrp-nautilus.io
        secretName: dask-jupyter-tls
    hostname: wifire-commons-pangeo-jupyter.nrp-nautilus.io  # Ingress hostname.
    annotations:  
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: haproxy
```

When I run the update, here’s my error:
$ helm upgrade pangeo -f values.yaml dask/dask

Error: UPGRADE FAILED: YAML parse error on dask/templates/dask-jupyter-ingress.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 19: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Does anyone have any suggestions for configuring the YAML for ingress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the charts documentation carefully you will see that your `values.yaml` is incorrect.
To enable ingress for charts that you are using please use following in values.yaml

```
dask:
  webUI:
    ingress:
      enabled: true
      tls: true
      secretName: dask-jupyter-tls
      hostname: wifire-commons-pangeo-jupyter.nrp-nautilus.io
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: haproxy
```

This will generate correct Ingress as:

```
# Source: ingresscontroller/charts/dask/templates/dask-scheduler-ingress.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dask-scheduler
  labels:
    app: dask-scheduler
    chart: "dask-4.5.7"
    release: "dask"
    heritage: "Helm"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: haproxy
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - "wifire-commons-pangeo-jupyter.nrp-nautilus.io"
      secretName: dask-jupyter-tls
  rules:
  - host: wifire-commons-pangeo-jupyter.nrp-nautilus.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: dask-scheduler
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Note I'm using chart version dask-2021.12.0.

Comment: I'm not seeing the Ingress generated when I run your suggested values.yaml. However, when remove the first line and use the following
```
webUI:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    tls: true
    secretName: dask-scheduler-tls
    hostname: wifire-commons-pangeo-jupyter.nrp-nautilus.io  
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: haproxy
```
and run 

$ helm upgrade pangeo -f values.yaml dask/dask --namespace wifire-quicfire

I get this error:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
```

Comment: What is your Kubernetes version?

Comment: $ kubectl version
```Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.7", GitCommit:"1dd5338295409edcfff11505e7bb246f0d325d15", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:23:52Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.5", GitCommit:"5c99e2ac2ff9a3c549d9ca665e7bc05a3e18f07e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-12-16T08:32:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} ```

Comment: helm version 3.7.1

Comment: Seems like your Kubernetes version is 1.22.x and apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1 for Kind Ingress is supported from Kubernetes version 1.22.x. You need to update your ingress to  apiVersion: extensions/v1

Comment: Do you have a reference for how to update ingress from extensions/v1beta1 to apiVersion: extensions/v1?

Comment: https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/1.3.x/concepts/ingress-versions/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: You were correct. The helm chart ingress template uses apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1 which is incompatible with my k8s cluster ingress which uses apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1.  I created a separate ingress based on apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 and it now works.  Thanks!